# Firefox ignores setting for new-tabs default page after update to V41

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

I use the [Super Start](http://www.enjoyfreeware.org/superstart) add-on with Firefox (it's a "speed dial" and organizer for URLs).  I have it set as the home page and the default content for new tabs.  Since Firefox was updated to version 41.0, this new-tab setting has been ignored.  New tabs now display Firefox's own feature, with tiles for frequently used URLs.

I've found instructions online for specifying a **URL** as the new-tab default (in `about:config`).  However, Super Start isn't a URL.  It has its own setup, which includes an option to use it for new tabs:

[image]

This has worked for previous versions of Firefox.  However, this setting is now ignored.  (Super Start still works if you open it via its toolbar icon).

How can I manually configure Firefox 41 to use an add-on, like Super Start, as the default display for new tabs?

Comment: (FYI -- browsers and browser extensions are not on-topic on web apps.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Mozilla Support Forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1085359):

> Firefox 41 no longer uses the browser.newtab.url setting in
>   about:config because it was constantly attacked by malware. Starting
>   in Firefox 41, you need an add-on to change the new tab page.

There are several questions about this on Mozilla's forum and many solutions.  I'll post several of the solutions here.

- If you already use the **Classic Theme Restorer** extension: There is an option in its extensive settings dialogs to select a different new tab page.

[image]

- If you want to use **your home page** on the new tab: Try https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/new-tab-homepage/ *[This was my situation.  I loaded this one and it worked.]*
- If you want to set a **different page or a completely blank page**: Try https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/new-tab-override/  *[More flexibility than the previous add-on.  Haven't tested it myself.]*

**Please only use one of these methods at a time, otherwise there may be conflicts and dysfunctionality.**

---

If you use the **New Tab Override** add-on (third bullet, above), you need to set it up.
**(the following instructions apply only to that add-on)**:

> After installing this extension, you need to use its Options page to
>   set the desired new tab page (instead of using about:config).
>
> Open the Add-ons page using either:
>
> - Ctrl+Shift+a (Mac: Cmd+Shift+a)
> - "3-bar" menu button (or Tools menu) > Add-ons
> - Or from the menu: Tools | Add-ons
>
> In the left column, click Extensions. Then on the right side, find New
>   Tab Override and click its Options button.

[image: screenshot1]

> Depending on the height of your screen, you may need to scroll down to
>   enter the desired address into the form.

[image: screenshot2]

> For example:
>
> - Page thumbnails (default) => about:newtab
> - Blank tab => about:blank
> - Built-in Firefox home page => about:home
> - Any other page => full URL to the page
>
> Then tab or click away from that form field and you can test using
>   Ctrl+t.